# How can I run Dwarf Fortress in text mode on my Linux VPS?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I installed Dwarf Fortress on my Linux VPS to use with dfterm. It's running Ubuntu 10.04. I'm fairly certain I have all the dependencies:

I've installed:

- ncurses
- ncursesw
- libsdl
- libsdl-image
- libgtk
- libglu
- libopenal1

I had to turn sound off or it will instantly segfault, and I set the display mode to text. I've made no other changes to the config.

However, even before I go near dfterm, it won't run properly. It just displays a blank screen. What could be causing this? Is their a dependency I missed? Is there something else I should have changed in the config?

**EDIT:** This has been [asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1626/how-can-i-run-dwarf-fortress-in-text-mode-ncurses-on-my-linux-vps) and answered on the Ubuntu StackExchange.

Comment: Is the Linux box 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: 32 bit. (and this 15 char limit is annoying me again)

Comment: And which version of DF are you trying to run?  0.31.12?

Comment: You might bet better help here: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I just retried it on my Ubuntu 9.04 server (which is just an old desktop with server installed, and it ran fine).  Out of curiosity do you have the intro turned off?

Comment: @C.Ross: Intro off, same result.

Comment: @tzenes: Asked there too now, link: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/how-can-i-run-dwarf-fortress-in-text-mode-ncurses-on-my-linux-vps

Comment: @Macha I also upgraded to Ubuntu 10, and it still works for me.  What terminal?

Comment: @C. Ross: SSH (gnome-terminal on the client system)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question was answered on the [Ubuntu Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/q/1626/912).  I've coppied [Bryce's](https://askubuntu.com/users/913/bryce) answer below and marked this answer as CW.  If you'd like to award him Rep please head over there and upvote his answer.

> I was able to recreate the segfaulting by running df on a regular Ubuntu install with X turned off.

```
...
(Dwarf_Fortress:5346): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_new: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed
Segmentation fault
```

> I suspect the problem is that this game expects to have a functioning GL driver available. And for that you need X running. But a VPS doesn't have X!
>
> Instead, use Xvfb, which is a "fake" virtual X. You'll need to install xvfb and whatever dependencies it wants (probably xorg-server-core and a bunch of other stuff that may not be installed on Ubuntu Server).
>
> Start the fake xserver up like this:

```
$ Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
```

> Then make sure your DISPLAY variable is pointed to it:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:1
$ ./df
```

> I also needed to disable sound and run in TEXT mode, but it worked this way, with no X running. I hope it works for you.

Comment: @Macha I didn't mean for you silly ;) , just anyone else finding this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change **df_linux/data/init/init.txt** and set `[PRINT_MODE:TEXT]` and `[SOUND:NO]` and you should be able to run in a terminal, and via SSH, etc. at a fixed size of 80x24.