# Can Dwarf Fortress be run in console mode?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, linux

I don't want to start up an X server at all, I just want to play on a text console. Is this possible?

Comment: Related questions on [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4716/how-can-i-run-dwarf-fortress-in-text-mode-on-my-linux-vps) and [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1626/how-can-i-run-dwarf-fortress-in-text-mode-ncurses-on-my-linux-vps)?

Comment: Similar, but not the same. That was about debugging an Ubuntu install using a virtual display. I was hoping there was a simpler way...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes.  You need to change the print mode to TEXT

```
Linux/OS X users may also use PRINT_MODE:TEXT for primitive ncurses output.

[PRINT_MODE:TEXT]
```

This is located in the `./df/data/init/init.txt` file.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to avoid installing the GTK shared lib?

Comment: @Alex I don't think so.  I *believe* it's statically linked so it has to be there to run.  Someone who writes more C than I do can correct that.